# call special function when DataFrame is called upon custom class

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oop, metaprogramming

I have the following classes:

```
class Result(UserDict):
    """Implements a especial version of dictionary, that will return the keys 
ordered in the initialized way"""
    def __init__(self, keys_order, items):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.__keys_order = keys_order
        self.data = items

    def __repr__(self):
        attributes = ["{}:{}".format(_stringify(k), _stringify(self.data[k])) for k in self.keys()]
        return "{}".format(", ".join(attributes))

    def keys(self):
        return [key for key in self.__keys_order]


class Results(UserList):
    """Implements a especial kind of list, that has a method to_df"""
    def to_df(self):
        return pd.DataFrame(self.data, columns=self.data[0].keys())
```

In this way, when I print an instance of `Result`, it will show it with the keys in the desired way (determined by `keys_order`). Also, the class `Results` implements the method `to_df`, which returns a pandas `DataFrame` with the columns ordered by the keys.

I know for example that if I want the `len(results)` function to behave in a especial way, I have to implement the `__len__` method in it, in a similar way, is it possible to implement a special method so when `pd.DataFrame(results)` is called upon a `results` instance it will call `to_df` method instead? so I have the columns ordered by the keys.

Comment: Can you please provide some example code that uses your classes and what kind of output you would expect?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your Result class inherit not just from UserDict but also from pd.DataFrame. Then you just have to define the _data attribute of your class to be what you want the class to hand to pd.DataFrame(), i.e. the pd.DataFrame that you want to be constructed.

```
class Result(UserDict, pd.DataFrame):
    """Implements a especial version of dictionary, that will return the keys 
ordered in the initialized way"""
    def __init__(self, keys_order, items):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.__keys_order = keys_order
        self.data = items
        self._data = pd.DataFrame(self.data, columns=self.data[0].keys())
```

This becomes evident when looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L236-L6142) of the pd.DataFrame class:

```
def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None,
             copy=False):
    if data is None:
        data = {}
    if dtype is not None:
        dtype = self._validate_dtype(dtype)

    if isinstance(data, DataFrame):
        data = data._data
```

upon calling the `__init__` method, which is what you are effectively doing when you use `pd.DataFrame(results)`, it will check if results is an instance of DataFrame. If it is, then it will just set data to be results._data. Alternatively your results class could also inherit from dict, in which case the dict constructor would be called inside the `__init__`:

```
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
```

Here the excerpt from self._init_dict that would be called in your case:

```
        else:
            keys = list(data.keys())
            if not isinstance(data, OrderedDict):
                keys = _try_sort(keys)
            columns = data_names = Index(keys)
            arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
```

So you have to define a `keys()` method for your class that returns the keys (which you already have), as well as `__getitem__`, so that data[k] in the last line returns the values of column k.

Comment: I tried to implement it in this way, but it didn't work :/. I can't create an object that is a child or UserDict and DataFrame or UserList or DataFrame, it threw different errors that I wasn't able to debug.
On the other hand, I don't actually want it to be initialized as a DataFrame, I want it to be a list of dicts, then, when I pass it through the DataFrame initializer I want it to automatically have the keys in a certain order.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you can alternatively try and inherit from dict instead. I can try this out when I find the time